# Converting R function to Latex formula

Tags: r, function, statistics, latex, formula

I'm having trouble converting an R function to a latex formula. I have a df (m) of x and y coordinates that I then calculate a centroid from using the following R function:

```
cnt = c(mean(m[,1]),mean(m[,2]))
```

I then take that same list and calculate the distance from each x,y pair to that centroid. Lastly, I then take the mean distance over all the records from the centroid using the following code:

```
mean_distance <- mean(apply(m,1,function(x,cnt) {(sqrt((x[1] - cnt[1])^2+(x[2]-cnt[2])^2))},cnt))
```

I think I got the first part figured out (finding the centroid coordinates)

```
cnt\left(x, y\right)   = \frac{\sum x_{i}}{n}, \frac{\sum y_{i}}{n}
```

I'm having trouble with the second calculation. I'm new to latex and would like to create (an elegant) formula to include in a paper I am writing. Is there any easy way to convert this R code to latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$$
C(x,y) = (C_1, C_2) = \left( \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)
$$

$$
d = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\left( x_i-C_1\right)^2+\left( y_i-C_2\right)^2}
$$
```

if I understood what you want.

Comment: A quick comment, the last part of the line should read  y_i-C_2\right)^2}